# G729 codec compiled for iOS arm64 does not function properly

Tags: ios, arm64, g729

I used G729 codec in my VOIP App, when the app target only armv7, it works fine. The Callee can hear my voice clearly. Then I turn to arm64, the callee no longer get my voice clearly. I record the input voice raw data before and after G729 codec both on armv7 device and arm64 device on the Caller side, and then convert the G729 encoded data back. I find the converted back voice from armv7 device is much better than arm64 device.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: could u plz share ur code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the G729 implementation you are using, but if you are using Samuel Vinson's, I believe I found the problem.

In `lpc.c` there is a comparison between a result and a subtraction between two values on lines 643 and 698 respectively:

```
lpc.c:643  if ((UWord32)(t0 - 0xfe000000L) < 0x01ffffffL -  0xfe000000L)
lpc.c:698  if ((UWord32)(t0 - 0xff000000L) < 0x00ffffffL -  0xff000000L)
```

The result of `0x00ffffffL - 0xff000000L` is `1ffffff` (`33554431`) on 32 bit, but `ffffffff01ffffff` (`-4261412865`) on 64 bit, because the long is way larger on 64 bit on an ARM processor (I am testing with an iPhone 4, armv7, 32 bit and an iPhone 5s, arm64, 64 bit).

So basically on 64 bit the comparison will always fail the check as the second term is always negative and a `UWord32` will always be positive.

My solution is to use the hardcoded results of the subtraction on 32 bit, so 
using `0x3ffffffL` for the first conditional and `0x1ffffffL` for the second, fixes the voice quality issue for me:

```
lpc.c:643  if ((UWord32)(t0 - 0xff000000L) < 0x3ffffffL)
lpc.c:698  if ((UWord32)(t0 - 0xfe000000L) < 0x1ffffffL)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You saved my life brother! Was digging out this for almost a month. Thanks you so much!! :)

Comment: Thank you so much - wish I could give this answer more upvotes

Comment: A slight correction is required; the 0xff000000L and 0xfe000000L have been swapped around in the solution

Comment: @NickDowell: I am struggling with compilation of G729 for ARM. It gives me error for asm. Any help!!

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz I've just followed the answer (edited) and got the result!

Comment: @Erfan can we chat i am facing compilation issue

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz okay then how can I help you?

Comment: @Erfan: Can We chat if you are available ?

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz sure!

Comment: @Erfan: I have added you in chat

Comment: I recommend using the g729 implementation from CSipSimple and applying the above changes - works for me!

Comment: I noticed that the compiler was complaining about the UWord32 cast and gave a warning when compiling for 64 bit so I was able to pinpoint the issue.